# Add a certain number of days for a date field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, date

I have one field for a permit decision date, and then I have another field for 180 days from that permit date. The permit date field has data entered, but the 180 day field I would like to calculate by adding 180 days. It is a feature class in a file GDB, and both fields are in date format (mm/dd/yyyy).

Example: Permit Field date is 7/1/2009, I would like the 180 days field to be 12/28/2009.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Comment: It is ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.2

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure this is what you are looking for:

[Simplify Date and Time Calculations](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/1210/tip.html)

> Calculating a Past or Future Date If your features have a single date
>   and time, and you need to calculate a second date or time relative to
>   the first, use the DateAdd function. It adds or subtracts a specific
>   interval from the original date and returns the resulting second date.